# Having some issues with basic login system

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need some help with a piece of my code that doesn't seem to be working, no matter how much I've tried to make it work, I can't seem to find the problem with it. It does say that the function `loginGo()` isn't defined but I can't see that.

**JavaScript**

```
var logins = [
  {
    username: "Firstuser"
    password: "12345"
  },
  {
    username: "Seconduser"
    password: "54321"
  },
  {
    username: "Thirduser"
    password: "98765"
  }
]

function loginGo() {
  var password = document.getElementById("password").value
  var username = document.getElementById("username").value
  for (i = 0; i < logins.length; i++) {
    if (username == logins[i].username && password == logins[i].password) {
      console.log(username + " is logged in, redirecting to the main page...")
      window.location.href = "conversioncalcHTML.html"
    } else {
      alert("Invalid username or password, please try again.")
    }
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="author" content-="Jay Lyle" />
    <meta name="description" content="Login page relating to the conversioncalcHTML page." />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="loginpage.css" />
    <title>Login page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2 class="title">Login page</h2>
    <p>Username:</p>
    <input name="Username" type="text" class="user" id="username" />
    <p>Password:</p>
    <input name="Passw" type="password" class="pass" id="password" />
    <button value="Click here to login" onclick="loginGo()" type="button"/>
    <button value="Back" type="reset" type="button"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How is the JavaScript added to that page?

Comment: Your HTML needs a `<script>` tag that includes the JavaScript inline or brings it in from an external source with the `src=` attribute. How is your JavaScript being included? I see no way.

Comment: Checking the uname/pw on the front end like this isn't secure at all. Even if it's just for fun, it doesn't make sense to store user objects in an array--faster and easier to have a single object with unique username keys mapped to passwords, saving the loop. Use `===` for equality checks.

Comment: @Ivar I forgot to mention the code in there but it's enclosed in some <script> tags and it's inside the HTML page.

Comment: @ggorlen Ahh I see what you mean, because you can just inspect the page and see the passwords straight up. I'll try that now.

Comment: Exactly. Passwords should be on the server and stored encrypted. Front end is never secure.

Comment: There are comma's missing after the usernames in your JS object. Other than that, it should work fine. Please provide a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem. (Also your loop will still go over _all_ the users, even if you enter the right credentials. It will still show the alert for the other ones.)

Comment: @ggorlen Preferably hashed rather than encrypted. Although for the authorization of the `conversioncalcHTML.html` page, it's not really going to help, as it seems that you can access it directly via the URL.

Comment: Also true. Yes, one-way hashing, not encryption. Thanks for clarifying.